# find DOM elements that have no attributes?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to find all `span` tags that have no attributes -- no class, no styling, no nothing. I've been doing this:

```
function hasAttributes(span) {
    if (span.outerHTML.slice(0,6) === '<span>') return true;
    return false;
}
```

Is there a better (faster) way to check if a particular element qualifies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll()` to select all `spans` and then use `for` loop to filter spans by [`attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes) property. If span doesn't have any attributes it will return empty array.

```js
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  if (spans[i].attributes.length == 0) spans[i].style.color = 'blue';
}
```

```html
<span>one</span>
<span class="two">Two</span>
```

Comment: assumes OP using jQuery though

Comment: That definitely works, but the time it would take to load jQuery would circumvent any benefit in time from another solution.

Comment: @Cliff  Updated with pure js solution.

Comment: @NenadVracar, that works! Out of curiosity, why use `document.querySelectorAll` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName`?

Comment: I prefer `querySelectorAll` but in this case you can also use `getElementsByTagName`

Answer (score 0):

Check attributes property of element for length

```
function hasAttributes(span){
    return span.attributes.length;
}
```